# Is google apps script V8 supposed to stop at try-catch when debugging?

Tags: google-apps-script, debugging, ide, try-catch

When I use the debugger in GAS and there is a try-catch section the debugger seems to stop in this section.

I thought that this was not the expected behavior in GAS V8, but is it the expected behavior. Is the only way around this to put code in a library, as I have read in a previous answer?

Also, I assume that I'm running V8, as I have this in my appscript.json file:
"runtimeVersion": "V8"

Can I assume that this means I'm running V8 or is there a way I should check this?

Comment: you can  look in the manifest or project settings

Comment: As far as the code question can you post a [mcve]

Comment: No, that's not expected behavior. If it stops there, there might be a bug in that block. `try catch` is a red herring